# Username only authentication with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

In my Spring Boot web app I want to integrate Spring Security for authentication. There are the following conditions:

- Only username must be given
- The username is set in a GET param (e. g. "username") and comes with the first request for a ressource
- No password is used
- Authentication will be done by searching for the username in a separate system (not defined right now)

Could someone outline what an appropriate solution with Spring Security might look like?

Answer (score 0):

Well if you do want to go this way you could go for basic auth with a custom filter as described here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-basic-authentication

The username would be passed on every request, not on a first request. What you seem to be suggesting with "first request" is some form of token based system that would be sent for all requests following the "authenticating" request.